# sql server database backup

Tags: sql-server, backup

I am having my sql server which is almost 10 GB of data in server A . and I need to get it through a backup restored in server B . however , the problem is that server A and server B are both in USA and i am in asia , and hosting company is asking me for $100 for that transfer , is there a way that i can make the backup between them quickly ? Note : I have sql server management studio to both servers .

Their suggested solution is that i download the database and reupload it , but that seems extremely hard and very long process.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the size of the **log file** (database properties, files, check the log file size)?

If it is taking most of the total space, you might opt to backup locally (just in case), change the the recovery model to simple, compact the database, backup it and this way might be of a size far more manageable for the transfer.

Comment: Even if it was reduced to 1 GB it would be slow , it would mean at least stopping the site for hours...

Comment: Well, you can take the time you need to transfer the DB to server B as i suggested, set the recovery mode of Server A to full, and then update the status of the server B [loading the changes from the log file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177446.aspx) of server A which would be of far smaller size. If the size is still considerable, you can loop as needed. The final run, which will take very small time, before transferring the file, you bring the WebApp in Server A down so that you are sure no data is lost.